# How to calculate Jaccard similarity between two data frame with in R

Tags: r, dataframe, similarity

I have two binary dataframes `c(0,1)`, and I didn't find any method which calculates the Jaccard similarity coefficient between both dataframes. I have seen methods that do this calculation between the columns of a single data frame.
Lets say `DF1`

```
DF1 <- data.frame(a=c(0,0,1,0),
                  b=c(1,0,1,0),
                  c=c(1,1,1,1))
```

and `DF2`:

```
DF2 <- data.frame(a=c(0,0,0,0),
                  b=c(1,0,1,0),
                  c=c(1,0,1,1))
```

What I am looking is a single Jaccard similarity coefficient between the two data frame (not column by column)

Could you help me with this ?

Comment: Do you mean the Jaccard similarity of every item `ij` of the data frames?

Comment: I mean, since the two data frames have the same rows and columns size, I am expecting a single (mean) Jaccard similarity between the two data frames.

Comment: I would suggest to do something like `jaccard(unlist(DF1),unlist(DF2))`

Comment: Can you just `unlist` the data frames and use the resultant vector?

Comment: @Marat Talipov, than you it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dist`:

```
dist(t(cbind(unlist(DF1), unlist(DF2))), "binary")
# 0.2857143
```

The distance would be `1` for `DF2 <- as.data.frame(xor(DF1, 1) +0L)` and `0` for `DF2 <- DF1`.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```
DF1<-data.frame(a=c(0, 0, 1, 0),
           b=c(1,0,1,0),
           c=c(1,1,1,1))

DF2<-data.frame(a=c(0,0,0,0),
               b=c(1,0,1,0),
               c=c(1,0,1,1))

install.packages("vegdist")
library(vegdist)
vegdist(rbind(unlist(DF1, use.names=F),unlist(DF2, use.names=F)), method = "jaccard")
```